# Deb package from kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel, dpkg

I slightly modified the cp210x.c, compiled it, and copied the cp210x.ko to the right place, everything went fine. Now I would like to create a .deb package from it, but I'm stucked. I followed the tutorial, I found here: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/how-to-create-deb-package-ubuntu-debian.html

In Step 3. I selected "kernel module" instead of "single binary".
Before Step 3. I only had a *Makefile* and the *cp210x.c* in the *mydriver-1.0* folder. The Makefile is very simpe:

`obj-m += cp210x.o
    KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)
    all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
    clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean`

After Step 3. I have the following structure:

`mydriver-1.0/
    ├── build-arch-stamp
    ├── build-indep-stamp
    ├── configure-stamp
    ├── cp210x.c
    ├── debian
    │   ├── changelog
    │   ├── compat
    │   ├── control
    │   ├── control.modules.in
    │   ├── copyright
    │   ├── docs
    │   ├── mydriver.cron.d.ex
    │   ├── mydriver.default.ex
    │   ├── mydriver.doc-base.EX
    │   ├── mydriver-modules-_KVERS_.postinst.modules.in.ex
    │   ├── mydriver-source
    │   │   └── usr
    │   │       └── src
    │   │           └── modules
    │   │               └── mydriver
    │   │                   └── debian
    │   ├── mydriver-source.debhelper.log
    │   ├── mydriver-utils
    │   ├── mydriver-utils.debhelper.log
    │   ├── init.d.ex
    │   ├── manpage.1.ex
    │   ├── manpage.sgml.ex
    │   ├── manpage.xml.ex
    │   ├── menu.ex
    │   ├── postinst.ex
    │   ├── postrm.ex
    │   ├── preinst.ex
    │   ├── prerm.ex
    │   ├── README.Debian
    │   ├── README.source
    │   ├── rules
    │   └── source
    │       └── format
    └── Makefile`

In Step 5 when I try enter

`dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot`

After a while I get this error:

`...
    # Copy only the driver source to the proper location
    cp -s driver/*  debian/mydriver-source/usr/src/modules/mydriver
    cp: cannot stat driver/*: No such file or directory
    debian/rules:130: recipe for target 'install' failed
    make: *** [install] Error 1
    dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2`

Here I'm stuckedI have no clue what is the "driver" folder, should I create it or not and what should I put in it. Google did not help me neither, so I'm grateful for any help.